# R: constructing a matrix based on expanding two lists

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix manipulation problem in R that I feel has to have been asked before but I haven't been successful in a search. So here goes.

I have two vectors:

```
x<- c(1,2,3)
y<- c(9, 10)
```

I would like to construct a 6x2 matrix:

```
1,9
1,10
2,9
2,10
3,9
3,10
```

Any suggestions (as well as your patience) is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `expand.grid`

```
as.matrix(expand.grid(y,x)[2:1])
```

Comment: awesome! not familiar with expand.grid so I gotta figure out what's going on here, but this worked right off and I haven't been able to break it.  thanks!

Comment: @Aengus expand.grid will create all the combinations of the two vectors.  Here, I used `(y,x)` because it will get the same order as you wanted and later I changed the order of columns(`[2:1]`).

Comment: the pointer to expand.grid is really the key. The example was just something simple to get at the general method without getting the discussion bogged down with reality.  A little embarrassing that I'm not familiar with expand.grid since it seems to have been written explicitly to deal with my problem (building a factor matrix). oh, well.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
cbind(rep(x, each = 2), y)
```